# Scala pattern match agains object in trait

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a trait containing multiple case classes and objects for example:

```
trait Logic[A <: Logic[A]] {
   case class And(l: Logic[A], l2: Logic[A]) extends Logic[A]
   trait Atom extends Logic[A]
   case object True extends Atom
   case object False extends Atom
 //  ...
}

trait LTLLogic extends Logic[LTLLogic]
object LTLLogic extends Logic[LTLLogic]
```

Now I want to match against a formula of type `Logic[A]`.

```
class Matcher[A <: Logic[A]] {

 def matchFormula(f: Logic[A]) = f match {
   case a: Logic[A]#And => //do something
   case Logic[A]#True => //<< not working
   case Logic[A]#False => //<< not working
   case _ => //other cases
 }

}
```

The problem is, matching against `Logic[A]#And` is working fine but I can't match against `True` and `False`. I could probably get it working if I match against the classes:

```
   case a:Logic[A]#Atom if a.getClass == a.True.getClass => //do something
   case a:Logic[A]#Atom if a.getClass == a.False.getClass => //do something
```

but I don't really like this solution. Is there any other way to make it working?

---

It looks like path-dependent types were not the right tool for this.
Moving the case classes/objects, as suggested, out of the `trait` into an `object Logic` and making `A` in Logic covariant seems to be working.

```
trait Logic[+A <: Logic[A]]
object Logic{
   case class And[A <: Logic[A]](l: Logic[A], l2: Logic[A]) extends Logic[A]
   trait Atom[A <: Logic[A]] extends Logic[A]
   case object True extends Atom[Nothing]
   case object False extends Atom[Nothing]
}
```

Comment: Is moving `Atom` out of the `Logic` declaration a possibility?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't think so. I have special (time related) atoms for the LTL, which are not needed in the other logic classes.

Comment: This feels a bit like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps try explaining what it is you're trying to achieve instead of a possible solution.

Comment: @Evox33, just to re-state Yuval's first question differently: why can't you move all subtypes of the `Logic[A]` trait to a companion `object Logic`? They will still be bound to `Logic` but will not be inner types of `Logic[A]` and thus will not require path-dependent types.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you were right. I actually tried placing the classes outside of the trait the first time, when I defined the trait, but I totally forgot about `Nothing` and I moved them into the trait to solve the problem, that objects can't have generic type-parameters. So thanks for your help.

@SergGr I don't know why I didn't realize this obvious possibility myself yesterday. Thanks.